# Are Google Drive API Download Links broken for Images?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-client

I´m using the Google Drive JS API to get a bunch of files and most things work as expected.

But there is one issue, and it seems like there is a bug on Googles API site, maybe I´m just not getting something though.

So here is what I do:
1) Authenticate via Oauth
2) Get the list of files via the "change" command (starting off with no changeID)

It works fine, and the URLs in the returned Object work as well. Except the "downloadUrl" for Images (mimeType: "image/jpeg"). I get something like this:

https://doc-10-5g-docs.googleusercontent.com/do(....)8996175007&e=download&gd=true

and it´s returning a 401 error

When removing the last parameter (to https://doc-10-5g-docs.googleusercontent.com/do(....)8996175007&e=download w/o the &gd=true) then the download link does work and it does download the file.

Am I just not getting something here or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same problem when i remove &gd=true from the download url it seems work great. But i do not know what is the right way to download the file content via API.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to download the files from JS API. But from objective C am using this to download the file content. You need to use their API to download the file content. In that way they will omit the "**&gd=true**" param from the download url link.

**Objective C Code to download the File data:**

```
- (void)loadFileContent {
NSString *downloadUrl = [[self.driveFiles objectAtIndex:selectedFileIdx] downloadUrl];

GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =
[self.driveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:downloadUrl];

[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"\nfile %@ downloaded successfully from google drive", [[self.driveFiles objectAtIndex:selectedFileIdx] originalFilename]);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

}